# Chrome developer tools can't detect manifest

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, manifest, progressive-web-apps

I have **manifest.json** and I added to my **HTML** with `<link rel="manifest" href="./manifest.json">`.

I think everything is fine but I can't figure out why chrome dev tools cant detect my manifest!

My **manifest.json**:

```
{
    "name": "Arman News",
    "short_name": "Ar News",
    "description": "This is my first try to make PWA webstie.",
    "theme_color": "#ffffff",
    "background_color": "#ffffff",
    "display": "standalone",
    "Scope": "/",
    "start_url": ".",
    "icons": [
      {
        "src": "img/icons/Icon-192.png",
        "sizes": "192x192",
        "type": "image/png"
      },
      {
        "src": "img/icons/Icon-512.png",
        "sizes": "512x512",
        "type": "image/png"
      }
    ],
    "splash_pages": null
  }
```

Comment: Try drop the dot in the path, to `href="/manifest.json"`

Comment: @LGSon I try it before :(

Comment: Try replacing `Scope` with `scope`. I think it's case-sensitive.

Comment: Well, the shouldn't be a dot in the path, so make sure there isn't, and also, the manifest's file extension should actually be `.webmanifest` (even though some browsers support others as well), so try that too, like this `<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.webmanifest">` ...and make sure the actual file is renamed too, **and** is stored in the _wwwroot_ folder.

Answer (score 1):

try navigate the manifest https://yourweb/manifest.json or .webmanifest

if KO add the following:

- add .json mime type in your server configurations 
  .json | application/json
- or rename manifest.json to manifest.webmanifest 
  .webmanifest | application/manifest+json

if OK look in dev tools under Application then Manifest

Answer (score 0):

Make sure both index.html and manifest.json are in same folder and refer it as below,

```
<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
```

Without the actual link to your site, this is all debugging we can provide for the given code. If this doesn't solve the issue, post screenshots of your network tab to know whats happening with manifest.json.

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than one .html file, then make sure you add

```
<link rel="manifest" href="./manifest.json">
```

to ALL of your .html files.  Even if you remembered to put it in all of them except for only one file, Chrome DevTools will say that it cannot detect any manifest.json file.